# form_set_error checkbox CCK 2 drupal 6

Tags: forms

How can I highlight the checkbox boxes when be validated a CCK field? (CCK 2.9). Data is validated correctly, and message is displayed correctly in the head of the form, but the checkboxes does not appear highlighted.

```
<?php    
$quantity_options = count($form_state['values']['field_checkboxes']);
if ($quantity_options > 2) {
form_set_error('field_checkboxes', 'message.');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look if the class `error` has been added to your `<input>`. It has on my side, it's the CSS that does not highlight the elements properly.

You can either adjust your stylesheet for `.form-item input.error` or you can use a piece of jQuery to make the parent of the radios styleable, such as

```
$('.form-radios:not(.error):has(.form-item input.error)').addClass('error');
```

Another option would be to add the appropriate class via the Drupal's theming system (`theme_optionwidgets_buttons()`).

Comment: thanks for your answer. the class error is in the checkbox. So I think that the problem is related with compatibility of CSS with checkboxes. for example (sucessfuly):

.form-item input[type="checkbox"].error{
    outline: 2px solid red;
}

so can be controlled using respective rules according crossbrowsers tips.